# Start foreground service from other apps share dialog in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

is it possible to create a service that will be started from other apps Share dialog ?
I want something similar to what happens when Clipboard item is selected

I try this,

```
 <service android:name=".HelloService"
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:host="www.youtube.com" android:mimeType="text/*" />
</intent-filter>
</service>
```

but it do not work

Comment: "is it possible to create a service that will be started from other apps Share dialog ?" -- not directly. `ACTION_SEND` is for activities, not services. "I want something similar to what happens when Clipboard item is selected" -- use a transparent activity, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot start service from other apps . when you start service you have to pass context of your application.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue by starting transparent activity and than start the service and finish my activity. from user perspective it looks liked starting service from other app.